# Filtering rows after using groupby() on a Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame(df_not2015)  that records the maximum and minimum temperature for each day from the year 2005 to 2014 something like this.

```
        max   min
day              
01-01  15.6 -16.0
01-02  13.9 -26.7
01-03  13.3 -26.7
01-04  10.6 -26.1
01-05  12.8 -15.0
```

There are 365 rows in this DataFrame, corresponding to each day of the year. (Leap years have been excluded for ease of calculation).
I have another DataFrame(df_2015) that contains the temperature records for the year 2015 only.

```
             ID        Date   Element   Data_Value
0   USC00205563  2015-01-03      TMIN         -3.9
1   USC00203712  2015-03-17      TMAX         18.9
2   USC00200032  2015-06-06      TMIN         12.8
3   USW00014833  2015-08-30      TMIN         17.8
4   USC00202308  2015-08-30      TMIN         15.6
```

The 'ID' column is the ID of the weather station where the temperature was recorded. Since the temperature on each day was measured multiple times, this DataFrame contains 13757 rows. TMAX and TMIN indicate whether that temperature is the maximum or minimum measured by that station.

**The problem:** From the second DataFrame (df_2015), I want to keep only those rows of temperature records of a particular day where the temperature is greater than the maximum or less than the minimum and assign Nan elsewhere For instance, suppose the temperatures measured on 2015-01-01 are [18,16,17,15,14,13,-11,-12,-17,-18] then I would only like to keep the rows with values [18,16,17,-17,-18] (upon comparing with the values in first DataFrame) and keep these values in different columns 'max' and 'min'

**Example** (not the actual data)

```
             ID        Date   Element   Data_Value
0   USC00205563  2015-01-01      TMIN         18
1   USC00203712  2015-01-01      TMAX         16
2   USC00200032  2015-01-01      TMIN         17
3   USW00014833  2015-01-01      TMIN         15
4   USC00202308  2015-01-01      TMIN         14
5   USC00205563  2015-01-01      TMIN         13
6   USC00203712  2015-01-01      TMAX        -11
7   USC00200032  2015-01-01      TMIN        -12
8   USW00014833  2015-01-01      TMIN        -17
9   USC00202308  2015-01-01      TMIN        -18
```

The intermediate DataFrame I am looking for is-

```
             ID        Date   Element   Data_Value   max     min
0   USC00205563  2015-01-01      TMIN         18      18     Nan
1   USC00203712  2015-01-01      TMAX         16      16     Nan
2   USC00200032  2015-01-01      TMIN         17      17     Nan
3   USW00014833  2015-01-01      TMIN         15      Nan    Nan
4   USC00202308  2015-01-01      TMIN         14      Nan    Nan
5   USC00205563  2015-01-01      TMIN         13      Nan    Nan
6   USC00203712  2015-01-01      TMAX        -11      Nan    Nan
7   USC00200032  2015-01-01      TMIN        -12      Nan    Nan
8   USW00014833  2015-01-01      TMIN        -17      Nan    -17
9   USC00202308  2015-01-01      TMIN        -18      Nan    -18
```

I would then like to drop the rows where both 'max' and 'min' are Nan to get the desired output-

```
             ID        Date   Element   Data_Value   max     min
0   USC00205563  2015-01-01      TMIN         18      18     Nan
1   USC00203712  2015-01-01      TMAX         16      16     Nan
2   USC00200032  2015-01-01      TMIN         17      17     Nan
8   USW00014833  2015-01-01      TMIN        -17      Nan    -17
9   USC00202308  2015-01-01      TMIN        -18      Nan    -18
```

**My approach:**
I first created two empty columns in the second DataFrame ('max') and ('min') assigned with Nan values. I removed the '2015' from the 'Date' column (so that the 'Date' column becomes the same as the index of df_not2015) and grouped it by 'Date'. Then I tried to apply a group-wise Boolean mask like so-

````
```python
for name, frame in df_2015.groupby('Date'):
    bool_1 = frame['Data_Value'] > df_not2015.loc[name, 'max']
    bool_2 = frame['Data_Value'] < df_not2015.loc[name, 'min']
    frame.where(bool_1, axis = 1, inplace = True)
    frame.where(bool_2, axis = 1, inplace = True)
```
````

This, however, throws a warning-
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

When I print df_2015, there is no change in the DataFrame. What is going on here?

Also, iterating through the groups doesn't seem very 'pandorable'. Is there a way to do this without the loops?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "For instance, suppose the temperatures measured on 2015-01-01 are [18,16,17,15,14,13,-11,-12,-17,-18] then I would only like to keep the rows with values [18,16,17,-17,-18]" - How did you come up with the 5 values there?

Comment: From the first DataFrame the 'max' on 01-01 is 15.6 and the 'min' is -16.0. Therefore, I would like to remove all values that satisfy **max <= value <= min** and that gives me [18,16,17,-17,-18]

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are trying to make changes to a copy of the dataframe (`df_2015.groupby('Date')`) and not the original dataframe (`df_2015`) and this is the same reason why nothing is updated in the original dataframe.

Try something like this:

```
temp_df = df_2015.groupby('Date')   
for name, frame in temp_df:
        bool_1 = frame['Data_Value'] > df_not2015.loc[name, 'max']
        bool_2 = frame['Data_Value'] < df_not2015.loc[name, 'min']
        frame.where(bool_1, axis = 1, inplace = True)
        frame.where(bool_2, axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

and then try printing the `temp_df` it will have the changes.

Comment: Nope, it did not work; same error as before. Although, I don't see how replacing df_2015.groupby('Date') with temp_df would change things because other steps are same as before. Essentially only the name has changed

Comment: It was because of the  `df_2015.groupby('Date') ` is updated when you try `inplace` and you can't access it after the loop